# Why \protect doesn't work with \linebreak?

Tags: line-breaking, titling

> This question is merely educational and it does not intent to find a solution to a problem, please don't provide an answer like "just use `\\` instead of `\linebreak`".

In the following code, the compiler returns an error `Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.`, which I guess is because `\linebreak` is fragile, and somehow using the `titling` package triggers it.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{My Custom Title}
\author{Author 1,\linebreak
Author 2}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The output of the code without using the `titling` package is
[image: Output without titling]

When adding the `\protect` keyword the output remains the same. However when adding the `\protect` keyword ***and using the package `\titling`***, the output is

[image: Output with titling]

## Note

The `\linebreak` could be replaced by `\\` which does not seem to be fragile, or at least, it doesn't give the error mentioned above.

Comment: The `titling` package puts the author(s) in a single-column `tabular`, so you must end rows in the way `tabular`s require, and `\linebreak` isn't one of them. Presumably `IEEEtran` does not put the authors in a `tabular`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `titling` package follows the standard classes `article`, `report` etc and implements `\maketitle` using a `tabular` to set the author, so `\\` here is the end of row in a `tabular` and `\linebreak` does nothing in a `c` column, so it is not really about robustness, and `\protect` therefore has no effect.